# Is it possible to create a nav slideshow using Canvas divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, canvas

I'm trying to implement the sliding nav as described in this simple tutorial: http://sixrevisions.com/tutorials/javascript_tutorial/create-a-slick-and-accessible-slideshow-using-jquery/

But rather than using images, I'd like to use charts from this charting package:

http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/how-to-use

I've found that whenever I try to put the code in to render the chart, the whole sliding nav falls apart.

I'm wondering if there's a problem combining the Canvas with the sliding code. Is there something inherent to the world of Javascript and Canvas that is preventing this from working?

Answer (score 0):

No. Making a sliding nav with canvas should be no problem.

Do you see any JavaScript errors?

Can you put something online for us to look at? (Can be very simple, as long as the problem occurs).